# How do I know if all values for a certain period are over 10?

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

this is example table in mysql.

```
----------------------
idx |company|data|date
0    |A     | 12 |2000-01-21
1    |A     | 11 |2000-01-22
2    |A     | 15 |2000-01-23
3    |A     | 15 |2000-01-24
4    |A     | 13 |2000-01-25
5    |B     | 13 |2000-01-21
6    |B     |  9 |2000-01-22
7    |B     | 11 |2000-01-23
8    |B     | 13 |2000-01-24
9    |C     | 13 |2000-01-22
10   |C     | 13 |2000-01-23
11   |C     | 13 |2000-01-24
12   |C     | 13 |2000-01-25
13   |C     | 13 |2000-01-26
----------------------
```

table above, in this case,
A and C company has a value of more than 10(Data column) during the period.
But B compnay is not due to idx 6.

I want to know A, C companies meet the condition. But B is not.
How do I know if all values for a certain period are over 10 using mysql or mariadb?

Comment: What certain period?

Comment: all day. A (01-21 ~ 01-25) B(21~24) C(22~26)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  Just look at the minimum value:

```
select company, min(data)
from t
group by company
having min(data) >= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the 'certain period', which remains unspecified, here's one idea...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.company 
           FROM my_table x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.company = x.company 
            AND y.data < 11 
          WHERE y.idx IS NULL;
```